# Unreadable Highlighting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

my highlighting colors in Visual Studio 2019 are off and i cant for the life of me find a way to correct it.
Maybe someone of you know the corresponding setting for this? See the screenshot below please.
Kind regards

[Screenshot: Visual Studio - Unreadable highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jiTp.png)

Comment: This site https://studiostyl.es/ could help you to find a color theme that you love. (PS. Not related to them in any way)

Comment: Maybe i really have to switch, but this one matches my OS perfectly: https://imgur.com/a/e5Hz0tC

Comment: It does not seem to be affected by the theme itself. I installed a theme from your site and still have the white highlighting. In the screenshots on the theme-website its different though. I have this problem only in Visual Studio. all other applications have correct highlighting - including vscode

Comment: Did you try to search into the menu _Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts And Colors_ ?. Here are stored all the color settings for Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes but i did not manage to change this explicit color. Maybe i overlooked it between the hundreds of font and color settings. Ill go through them again later when im done working. I even installed the theme editor but did not play around too much with it yet.

Comment: Ok, i nailed it down to that it is caused by some extension. I installed a fresh Visual studio in one of my VMs and applied the theme and there is no wrong highlighting. Then i disabled a bunch of extensions in my main IDE and the problem is gone for now. Since i need most of the extensions I will have to investigate what extension is causing it and how to prevent it. At least i think i maybe am moving in right direction now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
The highlighting comes from Productivity Power Tools.
If anyone else have this problem here is the answer to solve this:

https://github.com/Microsoft/VS-PPT/issues/148#issuecomment-325430623